# Problem with PHP Sessions to get it to echo to my html page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to figure out how to bring use session_start() to get the $name variable stored in my Mysql to echo it to my page. I have tried many different ways including $_GET['name'] but it is showing different kinds of error. Database, signup and login are working perfectly. Values are stored in Mysqli database. Any solution or help? Here is my code:

//php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name']) || empty($_SESSION['name'])){
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
}

$name = $_SESSION['name'];;

?>
```

//html:

```
<div class="response">
    <h2>Thank you, <?php echo $name; ?> for joining the waitlist!
    </h2>
    <br>
    <p>Here is your referral link: 
        https://mylink/waitlistRegister.php?refer=<?php echo $name; ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You do realize you aren't storing anything in $_SESSION here, right?

Comment: Yes the $_SESSION isn't storing anything. I am new and I am having the problem to figure out what to do to make the echo (<?php echo $name; ?>) work. The error is basically in the $name = $_SESSION['name']; line. If you could point me in a direction I would be grateful. Thanks -@Sherif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are not defining your session properly.

Try:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name']) || empty($_SESSION['name'])){
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
}

 $name = "Your Name";
 $_SESSION["name"] = $name; 

?>
 

<div class="response">
    <h2>Thank you, <?php echo $_SESSION["$name"];; ?> for joining the waitlist!
    </h2>
    <br>
    <p>Here is your referral link: 
        https://mylink/waitlistRegister.php?refer=<?php echo $_SESSION["$name"]; ?>
    </p>
</div>
```